# Performing the equivalent of a vlookup within a merged df in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I had no pandas/python experience this time last week so I have had a steep learning curve in trying to transfer a complex, multi-step process that was being done in excel, into pandas. Sorry if the following is unclear.

I merged 2 dataframes. I have a column, let's call it 'new_ID', with new ID names from originaldf1, some of which say 'no match was found'. For the 'no match was found' entries I would like to get the old ID number from originaldf2, which is another column in currentdf, let's call this col 'old_ID'. So, I would like to do something like an excel vlookup where I say: "if there is 'no match was found' in col 'new_ID', give me the ID that is in col 'old_ID', in that same row". The output I would like is just a list of all the old IDs where no match was found.

I've tried a few solutions that I found on here but all just give me blank outputs. I'm assuming this is because they aren't searching *each individual* instance of "no match found". For example I tried:

```
deletes = mydf.loc[mydf['new_ID'] == "no match was found", ['old_ID']
```

this turns out with just the col header, then all blank.

is what i'm trying to do possible in pandas? or maybe i'm stuck in excel ways of thinking, and there is a better/different way!?...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK2FZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Python. What you are trying to do is a straightforward task in pandas. Each column of a [pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) is a Series object; basically a list of values. You are trying to find which row numbers (aka indeces) satisfy this criteria: `new_id == "no match was found"`. This can be done by pulling the column out of the dataframe and applying a lambda function. I would recommend pasting this code in a new file and playing around to see how it works.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create test data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('new_id','old_id'))
df.loc[0] = (1, None)
df.loc[1] = ("no match", 4)
df.loc[2] = (3, None)
df.loc[3] = ("no match", 4)
print("\nHere is our test dataframe:")
print(df)

print("\nShow the values of the 'new_id' that meet our criteria:")
print(df['new_id'][lambda x: x == "no match"])

# Pull the index from these rows
indeces = df['new_id'][lambda x: x == "no match"].index.tolist()
print("\nIndeces:\n", indeces)

print("\nShow only the rows of the data frame that match 'indeces':")
print(df.loc[indeces]['old_id'])
```

A couple of notes about this code:

- `df.loc[]` refers to a specific row of a data frame. `df.loc[2]` refers to the 3rd row (since pandas data frames are generally [zero-indexed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html))
- A lambda function here takes each value of a list (or Series object) individually and plugs these values one-by-one into a function. In this case we are referring to each value of 'new_id' as 'x', and then checking if `x == "no match"`. Placing brackets `[]` around it converts the output to a list. So in this case the output of `[lambda x: x == "no_match"]` will be a list of True or False values. The list is then applied to our Series object, so that only the rows with `True` are returned.
- After the lambda function `.index.tolist()` is applied to convert the Series object to a list of its indeces.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i'll try this today and report back :)

Comment: i said i'd report back, and... i keep getting a blank result. this may be due to some small typo or something on my part so i'm currently checking and rechecking everything, but i also edited my original post to show an example of how the df looks, in case that changes anything! thanks

Comment: yep it was my fat fingers! it worked - you are amazing, thank you! i tried to upvote your answer but i'm too new :( sending you good karma though!

Answer (score 0):

Working off your example im going to assume all `new_ID` entries are numbers only unless there is no match.

so if your dataframe looks like this (assuming this 2nd column has any values, i didnt know so i put 0's)

| new_ID | originaldf2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| no match | 4 |

Next we can check to see if your `new_id` column has an id or not by seeing if it contains a number using `str.isnumeric()`

```
has_id =df1.new_ID.str.isnumeric()
has_id>>>

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: new_ID, dtype: bool
```

Then finally we'll use `where()`
what this does it takes the first argument `cond` that we've passed the `has_id` bollean filter through and checks whether its `True` or `False`. If true, it keeps original value, if false, goes to the argument found in `other` which in this case we assigned to the second column of our dataframe.

```
df1.where(has_id, df.iloc[:,1], axis=0)>>>
  new_ID old_df_2
0   1   0
1   2   0
2   3   0
3   4   4
```

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to reply to me! new_ID entries are confusingly a combination of letters and numbers - the format is predictable, but the number of digits/characters is not. they look like this: "12345678_somename". i should have made that clear...

Comment: Can you update your post with an example of the data frame you're working with?  It would help to have the shape and the data types, pattern of data etc.

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to actually paste it in as code but i added a link to a half-assedly anonymised version of how the df is structured :)

Comment: update - i eventually got the other suggestion to work - thank you for your reply though!